How can I fix this neural network model so that it matches the scheme?
I'm starting to study neural networks and I can't complete such a task. Here's the assignment.
Create a class called MyModel, with which you can create a neural network, as in the picture. In this model, each subsequent linear layer has one neuron less than the previous one. When creating the MyModel class, use the nn.ModuleList class.
Create a neural network model with an input tensor size of 20 and an output tensor size of 10. Write the result to the model variable.
here is the scheme
This is the code I got:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inp, out):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        layers = []
        for i in range(9):
            layers.append(nn.Linear(inp, inp - 1))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU())
            inp -= 1
        layers.append(nn.Linear(inp, out))
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x

model = MyModel(inp=20, out=10)

Here is the error that comes out when executing this code: "The created model does not match the model in the diagram. Note that the size of the input and output tensors on the inner layers do not depend on the size of the tensor at the entrance to and exit from the network."
But I can't figure out where the error is, please help me figure it out

Your homework wants the model to follow the 19 ... 11 scheme for any input/output value, while your code only reproduced that for specifically inp=20, out=10

And how do I make it work for any inputs/outputs?

Your problem is that inp doesn't change in your for loop, so all of your layers have the same number of neurons.

You can use nn.Sequential to combine all layers easily and nn.LazyLinear for the first layer, which accepts all input sizes.
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_first=19):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        layers = [nn.LazyLinear(out_first)]
        out = out_first
        for _ in range(9):
            layers.append(nn.ReLU())
            layers.append(nn.Linear(out, out - 1))
            out -= 1
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

model = MyModel()

